# Title Bar gets hide when Softkeyboard pops up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I have a custom Title Bar so I want that when the user types the username and password in Login Activity the Title Bar shouldn't hide. But, unfortunately it does get hide. I tried using `android:windowSoftInputMode= "adjustPan` but still the Title Bar gets hide.

> So, how can I show both Title Bar and Softkeyboard?

Here are my screen shot,

> This is my Login Activity

[image]

> This is when I click on the EditText and the Title Bar gets Hide.

[image]

> This is my xml for Login Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tbl_layout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <TableRow android:weightSum="10">
            <TextView android:layout_weight="3" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Username:"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_purple" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/et_username" 
                android:layout_weight="7" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Username"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_select"
                android:padding="8dip"
                 />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:weightSum="10" android:layout_marginTop="10dip">
            <TextView android:layout_weight="3" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Password:"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_purple" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/et_password" 
                android:layout_weight="7" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Password"
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:password="true"
                android:padding="8dip"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_select"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_below="@id/tbl_layout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_login" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Login" android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:onClick="myOnClick"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/dark_purple"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Being an efficient stackoverflow user, you should post here XML layout here as you facing a problem in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you have taken all the views just in one `RelativeLayout`.

And also if you taken `ScrollView` then put the Titlebar textview outside the ScrollView. I was facing the same issue and had resolved by making this trick.

And if you post the XML layout here then it would be great to rectify the exact problem.

Comment: I posted xml now, but before this what was your answer, that should have been in the comment part.

Comment: Where you have taken Title TextView? is it in ViewStub or else?

Comment: I am not using ScrollView as there is not need for scroll here.

Comment: I got hint from your answer, about putting my layout inside a scrollView and it worked for me. Thanks.